# Maven deploy Github Packages: How can I make it override the previous assets?

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm currently deploy artifact to Github Packages. I have a Github Actions that will publish to package everytime I push new commit.

But, everytime it publish, it create a new file, for example: "something-1.0-20230722.094753-1.jar"

What I want is to make it override the previous, not create a new file!

I have try to change the command like "mvn deploy -Dversion=1.0", but doesn't work.